# Как перезапустить программу в случае ошибки, не задействуя снова терминал?

Tags: python, requests, telebot

У меня есть простой *телеграм-бот*, который просто с помощью модуля
**request.get().status_code** возвращает код ошибки\успеха.
Часто возникают ошибки связанные с сервером, который либо отвечает либо не отвечает. Проблема в чём - если возникает ошибка связанная с модулем, то программа сразу прекращается и бот перестаёт работать.

```
def check_address(message):
send = bot.send_message
uid = message.chat.id
server = message.text
try:
    response = int(requests.get(server).status_code)
    print(response)
except Exception:
    send(uid, f'Упс! Произошла ошибка! Либо сервер не существует или подключится в нему невозможно!\nДата:{day}.{month}.{year} в {hour}:{minute}')
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv) #Здесь я попробовал исправить ситуацию, но результат который я получил - код 0 в случае ошибки
if response == 200:
    send(uid, 'Адрес существует! Можно по нему переходить!')
elif response == 404:
    send(uid, 'Страница запрашиваемого ресурса не существует либо нет прав для просмотра этой страницы')
else:
    send(uid, f'Неизветсная ошибка. Сервер не принял наш запрос. \nКод ошибки:{response}\nДата: {day}.{month}.{year} в {hour}:{minute}')
```

Что можно сделать чтобы код не прекращал работать а сразу же перезапускался? Я хочу поставить бота на хостинг, а из-за "неправильных запросов" бот просто не может обработать это все и вырубается.

Comment: Пробовали просто в цикл это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Может помочь цикл while и try/except в ней

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_bot(TOKEN)
    while True:
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```

Comment: вместо os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv) поставь return

Comment: Поставив return, это решило проблему не закрывания программы, но породило проблему конфликта библиотек. telebot и request